# Why image is not showing up in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiimageview

I'm having issue with a simple code downloading a remote image and adding content to an UIImageView object through its **'image'** property. Instead of showing the downloaded image, it shows an old picture. Any caching responsible ? I've reset anything and removed cache files but still don't understand why this old image is still showing.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Set appIcon and clear temporary data/image
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:self.activeDownload];

    if (image.size.width != kAppIconHeight && image.size.height != kAppIconHeight)
    {
        CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(kAppIconHeight, kAppIconHeight);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
        [image drawInRect:imageRect];
        self.image_view.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    else
    {
        self.image_view.image = image;
    }

    self.activeDownload = nil;
    [image release];

    // Release the connection now that it's finished
    self.imageConnection = nil;

    // call our delegate and tell it that our icon is ready for display
    [delegate appImageDidLoad:self.indexPathInTableView];
}
```

Comment: Could you show some code, please?

Comment: are you using the same image name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call [imageView setNeedsDisplay] after setting image property.